# Caching issue on a live react site

Tags: reactjs, caching, deployment, live

I have a live site built with react boiler plate. When I deploy the site to live, some users will still have the older version of the site unless they do a hard reload. How do I make it so that when a new version is released their cache is cleared automatically? Much thanks!

Comment: When they perform a hard reload, does the site revert to the older version on subsequent visits?

Comment: yes it seems like the user is constantly on the older version unless they clear their cache.

Comment: How have you built your app? Is it create-react-app with the default service worker enabled?

Comment: Ah, I'm using react-boiler-plate with nginx, does that have anything to do with it?